# Excluding a file or directory from .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

You had a great response that helped me resolve my .htaccess issue on GoDaddy. This was the code you provided:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

QUESTION: How can I exclude a file and/or directory from being rewritten?

Thanks!
David

Comment: You have no other questions. How can anybody have provided an answer to you?

Comment: That is your 1s question on SO but above code looks like one of mine :) however you never asked the question before

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to redirect `/ignore.php`. Modify above code like this:

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ignore\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ignore$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Thanks so much!  Is there a way I may compensate you for your time?

Comment: @user2233548: You're welcome, Just accepting (clicking tick mark next to) my answer would be enough :P